# Remove the terminated containers of a certain image

Tags: windows, powershell, docker

I just found out I have many containers that has been terminated by `docker kill` command. The containers are based off of `alpine:3.10`. I'd like to remove these by `docker rm`. I have some other terminated containers that I'd like to keep.
What I don't know is how to get the list of containers and filter based on image and status.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The short answer

```
docker rm $(docker container ls -aq --filter "status=exited" --filter="ancestor=alpine:3.10")
```

---

### The long one

- `docker rm` remove all container ids it gets passed via the subcommand
- `docker container ls` lists you all running containers by default
- adding the `-a` flag lists all containers (created, exited, running,...)
- adding the `-q` flag prints only the container id and not the entire table
- with `--filter "status=exited"` we select only the terminated containers
- with `--filter "ancestor=alpine:3.10"` we select all containers based on the image specified

---

### The Doc

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/